# JDBC delete method seems to not be working in my Spring Boot service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, crud

I'm trying to create a simple JDBC method to delete from my DB, and I'm not sure if I'm going about this the correct way. This is inside one of my services.

Method:

```
public void deleteLocation(Integer id) {
    String DELETE = "DELETE FROM locale WHERE id=?";
    namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(DELETE, new BeanPropertySqlParameterSource(id));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing your `update` line to
`namedParameterJdbcTemplate.update(DELETE, id);`.

Comment: I tried to do that but ended up with the error - "Cannot resolve method 'update(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer)'"

Comment: Can you add some more information? Usually the compiler tells more about the error. I think it would be easier to think about the problem, if you pass more info. Maybe add more code or error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-boot. Then you should be using spring-data-jpa to manage your database. Jdbc is Hard way of doing this.

If you are using jdbc delete to a specific row use prepared statement. You can refer this:

```java
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE * from table_name WHERE id= ?");
preparedStatement.setInt(1, id);
return !preparedStatement.execute();
```